# How do I climb the Galata tower in 60 seconds?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

When Ezio gets the hookblade in Constantinople, there is an optional objective to climb the Galata tower in 60 seconds. I have tried this quite a few times, but my best runs are still 5-10 seconds too slow.

I've basically just been following the route that Yusuf takes and mashing the hook-jump button whenever I'm moving vertically. It doesn't seem like I'm making any major time-wasting mistakes.

Do I need to take a different route from Yusuf? Or do I just need to follow him and somehow improve my hook-jump timing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to just follow him and you should make it.  You'll want to stay in **High Profile** though throughout the climb.  Don't ever stop and don't just mash the jump button, that won't help.  Just note that when you do the hook climb, you'll jump up, hook onto a ledge, and jump again.  So you're making two strides.

By the time you reach the first big window, you shouldn't be trying to jump anymore.  Just climb straight up.  You should be able to even catch up to him before you reach the top.

Comment: Sigh. I try over and over, quit for the night and ask the question. I come back later, and, of course, I get it done on the first try.